# Launching Chrome on Linux - missing libraries

Tags: rhel, chrome

Having downloaded chromium linux 512476, I get this error:

```
-bash-4.1$ ./chrome
./chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libminigbm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

`readelf -d` shows the following needed libraries:

```
-bash-4.1$ readelf -d chrome | grep NEEDED
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libminigbm.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnss3.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnssutil3.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libsmime3.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libnspr4.so]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdbus-1.so.3]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libfontconfig.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libexpat.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libX11.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libX11-xcb.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libxcb.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXcursor.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXext.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXi.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXrender.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libasound.so.2]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libwayland-egl.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libffi.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
```

The list of installed libraries given by `ldconfig –p` is too big to include here.

I'm not a Linux guy, any idea what I need to do to solve it?

h2. EDIT

Distribution: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)`

`ldd chrome` output:

```
./chrome: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./chrome)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeaa0e3000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5d572ef000)
        libminigbm.so => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5d570ea000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5d56ee2000)
        libnss3.so => /usr/lib64/libnss3.so (0x00007f5d56b9e000)
        libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib64/libnssutil3.so (0x00007f5d56971000)
        libsmime3.so => /usr/lib64/libsmime3.so (0x00007f5d56745000)
        libnspr4.so => /lib64/libnspr4.so (0x00007f5d56506000)
        libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib64/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f5d562c5000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f5d5608f000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f5d55e66000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f5d55b29000)
        libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f5d55928000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f5d55708000)
        libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f5d554fe000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f5d552ec000)
        libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f5d550dc000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f5d54ed3000)
        libasound.so.2 => /lib64/libasound.so.2 (0x00007f5d54be8000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5d54963000)
        libwayland-egl.so.1 => not found
        libffi.so.6 => not found
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5d5474c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5d543b8000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000037cd400000)
        libplc4.so => /lib64/libplc4.so (0x00007f5d541b3000)
        libplds4.so => /lib64/libplds4.so (0x00007f5d53fae000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f5d53d11000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f5d53b0d000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f5d53908000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome isn’t supported on RHEL 6 any more (and hasn’t been for a long time). Your best bet to get a similar browser working is to install the Chromium package:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-6-server-supplementary-rpms
yum install chromium-browser
```

See [Enabling Supplementary and Optional Repositories](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_subscription_management/1/html/rhsm/supplementary-repos) and the [`chromium-browser` package information](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/chromium-browser/62.0.3202.89-1.el6_9/x86_64/fd431d51/package) for more details. [Richard Lloyd’s page](https://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/) has more information on the Chrome on RHEL 6 situation.